# Using InputMappedClassifier From Command Line

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I'm trying to run a classifier with the InputMappedClassifier, since I know the test arff is missing some attributes in the training arff. However, when I run:

```
java -cp ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.misc.InputMappedClassifier -t aa/lang-train.arff \
-T aa/lang-test.arff -W weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -classifications \ 
weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.PlainText
```

It generates the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid class index: 2466
    at weka.core.Instances.setClassIndex(Instances.java:1293)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.getStructure(ConverterUtils.java:346)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.AbstractOutput.printClassifications(AbstractOutput.java:625)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.AbstractOutput.print(AbstractOutput.java:702)
    at weka.classifiers.evaluation.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1572)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:649)
    at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.runClassifier(AbstractClassifier.java:297)
    at weka.classifiers.misc.InputMappedClassifier.main(InputMappedClassifier.java:943)
```

If I run it without `-classifications`, it works. How can I get the classifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving the InputMappedClassifier the wrong options. It's complaining that you are giving it the training (-t) and test (-T) data. It supports the following:

```
Options specific to weka.classifiers.misc.InputMappedClassifier:

-I
    Ignore case when matching attribute names and nominal values.
-M
    Suppress the output of the mapping report.
-trim
    Trim white space from either end of names before matching.
-L <path to model to load>
    Path to a model to load. If set, this model
    will be used for prediction and any base classifier
    specification will be ignored. Environment variables
    may be used in the path (e.g. ${HOME}/myModel.model)
-W
    Full name of base classifier.
    (default: weka.classifiers.rules.ZeroR)
-output-debug-info
    If set, classifier is run in debug mode and
    may output additional info to the console
-do-not-check-capabilities
    If set, classifier capabilities are not checked before classifier is built
    (use with caution).
```

So your command should look like this:

```
java -cp ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.misc.InputMappedClassifier -W weka.classifiers.trees.J48 \
-t aa/lang-train.arff \
-T aa/lang-test.arff \
-classifications weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.PlainText
```